# Avoiding repetitive code in python and reuse the existing code

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-reuse, sap-gui

I am doing some screen **scraping** from one of my applications that I work on and the  a section of the code is becoming repetitive. How do I avoid repetitive code and reuse the earlier part of the code? There are no errors in the code only the repetitive part is making the code hard to maintain.

Below is my logic/pseudo code :

1. Read the department name from excel.
2. Login to the application
3. loop to get the department name.
4. Enter the department and date range to get all the list of employees in screen A
5. Screen B Copy the employee id from each row.
6. Go to screen C see if the employee is active or has rejoined back based on the extension beside the id
7. Go to screen D enter the employee details to check the training's completed.
8. Copy the data base on the date range mentioned earlier.
9. Go back to screen A follow the steps until Screen B select the row of that eid and close it if the dates match in the screen D.
10. Then select the next row and follow the entire process again.

This is the actual code :

```
import win32com.client
import sys
import subprocess
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from multiprocessing import Process

eid = pd.read_excel(r'C:\employee\ee_details.xlsx'
                  ,sheet_name='Sheet1'
                  ,header=0
                ,dtype=str
                )
to_day= datetime.today()
raaweekday = datetime.today().weekday()
friday=datetime.today() - timedelta(days=to_day.weekday()-3)
friday=friday.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
print(friday)

monday=datetime.today() - timedelta(days=to_day.weekday())
monday=monday.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
print(monday)
j=[]
to_day=to_day.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
for i in eid['Dept']:
    j = i
    print(j)

def saplogin():
    try:
        path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe'
        subprocess.Popen(path)
        time.sleep(10)
        SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject('SAPGUI')
        if not type(SapGuiAuto) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            return
        application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
        if not type(application) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            SapGuiAuto = None
            return
        connection = application.OpenConnection("EQ2", True)
        if not type(connection) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            application = None
            SapGuiAuto = None
            return
        
        session = connection.Children(0)           
        if not type(session) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            connection = None
            application = None
            SapGuiAuto = None
            return
        
       # Login to SBS BANKING
        session.findById("wnd[0]").Maximize
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").Text = username
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").Text = password
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").selectedNode = "0000000077"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").doubleClickNode("0000000077")
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(2)

        b = 0
        while b < len(eid['Dept']):
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_BR").Text = eid['Dept'][b]
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_DISBDT-LOW").text = "07/01/2019"
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_DISBDT-HIGH").text = to_day
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_IMPDT-LOW").text = "07/01/2019"
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_IMPDT-HIGH").text = to_day
            session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVkey(8)
        
            grid=session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell")
            cntRows = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").RowCount
            i=0
            while i < cntRows:
                rowValue= session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").GetCellValue(i,"ZCOMMENTS")
                if rowValue=="Training Completed":
                    global eid
                    eid=session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").GetCellValue(i,"Z_EID")                    
                    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(3)
                    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(3)
    
                    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "FPP3"
                    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)
                    fpp3=session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtBUS_JOEL_MAIN-OPEN_NUMBER").Text=eid['Dept'][b]+eid+"-A"
                    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()
                    pp3=session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSCREEN_3000_RESIZING_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:2036/subSCREEN_1010_LEFT_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:3100/tabsGS_SCREEN_3100_TABSTRIP/tabpBUS_LOCATOR_TAB_02/ssubSCREEN_3100_TABSTRIP_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:3200/subSCREEN_3200_SEARCH_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:3211/subSCREEN_3200_SEARCH_FIELDS_AREA:SAPLBUPA_DIALOG_SEARCH:2100/txtBUS_JOEL_SEARCH-PARTNER_NUMBER").Text = eid['Dept'][b]+eid+"*"
                    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSCREEN_3000_RESIZING_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:2036/subSCREEN_1010_LEFT_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:3100/tabsGS_SCREEN_3100_TABSTRIP/tabpBUS_LOCATOR_TAB_02/ssubSCREEN_3100_TABSTRIP_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:3200/subSCREEN_3200_SEARCH_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:3211/subSCREEN_3200_SEARCH_BUTTON_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:3240/btnBUS_LOCA_SRCH01-GO").press()
                    p = 0
                    orgRole = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSCREEN_3000_RESIZING_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:2036/subSCREEN_1010_LEFT_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:3100/tabsGS_SCREEN_3100_TABSTRIP/tabpBUS_LOCATOR_TAB_02/ssubSCREEN_3100_TABSTRIP_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:3200/subSCREEN_3200_SEARCH_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:3211/subSCREEN_3200_RESULT_AREA:SAPLBUPA_DIALOG_JOEL:1060/ssubSCREEN_1060_RESULT_AREA:SAPLBUPA_DIALOG_JOEL:1080/cntlSCREEN_1080_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").RowCount
                    
                    while p < orgRole:
                        training=session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSCREEN_3000_RESIZING_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:2036/subSCREEN_1010_LEFT_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:3100/tabsGS_SCREEN_3100_TABSTRIP/tabpBUS_LOCATOR_TAB_02/ssubSCREEN_3100_TABSTRIP_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:3200/subSCREEN_3200_SEARCH_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:3211/subSCREEN_3200_RESULT_AREA:SAPLBUPA_DIALOG_JOEL:1060/ssubSCREEN_1060_RESULT_AREA:SAPLBUPA_DIALOG_JOEL:1080/cntlSCREEN_1080_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").GetCellValue(p, "TRAINING")
                        print(training)
                        time.sleep(10)
                        p+=1
                        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(3)
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "FPL9"
                        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtFKKL1-GPART").text = training
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cmbFKKL1-LSTYP").key = "COMPLETED_OPEN"
                        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)
                        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(3)
                        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(3)

                        #Code that is being to repeat how to avoid the below code and re-use the above code
#             # going back to the impound screen
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").selectedNode = "0000000077"
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").doubleClickNode("0000000077")
                        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(2)
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_BR").Text = eid['Dept'][b]
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtS_CO-LOW").Text =eid
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_BR").Text = eid['Dept'][b]
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_DISBDT-LOW").text = "07/01/2019"
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_DISBDT-HIGH").text = to_day
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_IMPDT-LOW").text = "07/01/2019"
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_IMPDT-HIGH").text = to_day
                        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVkey(8)
                        #session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").Select
                        time.sleep(10)
                        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(3)
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_BR").Text = eid['Dept'][b]
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtS_CO-LOW").Text =""
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_BR").Text = eid['Dept'][b]
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtS_CO-LOW").Text =eid
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_BR").Text = eid['Dept'][b]
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_DISBDT-LOW").text = "07/01/2019"
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_DISBDT-HIGH").text = to_day
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_IMPDT-LOW").text = "07/01/2019"
                        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_IMPDT-HIGH").text = to_day
                        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVkey(8)
                        next
#                         session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_BR").Text =eid['Dept'][b]
                       
                b+=1
        print(b)
    
    except:
        print("NOT WORKING")
    finally:
        session = None
        connection = None
        application = None
        SapGuiAuto = None

saplogin()
```

Comment: Try using an IDE like PyCharm. They offer in-built code-refactoring solutions. You can just select the repetitive part of the code and refactor it into a reusable method. It even has an option of replacing the repetitions with the method call.

Comment: @ rdas could i use PyCharm in Anaconda -- I dont have the option of downloading IDE that is not authorized for me

Answer (score 1):

If you have stuff that needs to be done multiple times, you have to repeat the code. No way around that. You can only simplify.

1. Everything that is called more than twice should be called once and assigned to an object. That way you save a lot of time. I assume that the contains of `session` does not change during your **scraping**. Hence, `session.findById("wnd[0]")` could be stored in an variable for faster reference.
2. Put code that is repeatedly called into a function. For example:

   ```
               session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_BR").Text = eid['Dept'][b]
               session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtS_CO-LOW").Text =eid
               session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_BR").Text = eid['Dept'][b]
               session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_DISBDT-LOW").text = "07/01/2019"
               session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_DISBDT-HIGH").text = to_day
               session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_IMPDT-LOW").text = "07/01/2019"
               session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_IMPDT-HIGH").text = to_day
               session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVkey(8)
   ```

into a function `do_stuff(session)` that accepts the `session`- object to get the right context.
That way you only have to maintain the function and every call to the function reduces your maintenance workload.

3. Put all your ID-strings like `"wnd[0]"` into a dictionary with a "speaking" index. That way you avoid spelling errors and save a lot of debugging time due to misspelled ID strings.

Would it be possible for you to dump all your data into data frames? So Screen A into one, Screen B into another on, C and D as well? If so, you might be able to get the same result be clever merging and joining of the tables using the Pandas API.